# Scala, Tupler type back to an HList

Tags: scala, shapeless

suppose I have an available tupler in a simple class

```
class Tupling[L <: HList, TP](tupler:Tupler.Aux[L, TP])
```

such that I can create a function which accepts a corresponding tuple as an argument

```
def toHlist(value:TP):L
```

how can I implement the function: `toHList`?

I find the following does not work

```
def toHlist(value:TP):L =
  shapeless.syntax.std.tuple.productTupleOps(value).productElements
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we look at the implementation of the two shapeless functions you are using in `toHList` :

- [`productTupleOps`](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/shapeless/syntax/std/tuples.scala#L22) has a type parameter with `Product` as upper bound, so you need to specify that `TP` is a `Product`.
- [`productElements`](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/shapeless/syntax/std/tuples.scala#L39) needs an `Generic` type class instance for the tuple `value`.

Your `Tupling` class then could look like :

```
class Tupling[L <: HList, TP <: Product](tupler: Tupler.Aux[L, TP]) {
  def toHList(value: TP)(implicit gen: Generic.Aux[TP, L]): L = 
    shapeless.syntax.std.tuple.productTupleOps(value).productElements
}
```

You could also just use the implicit conversion `productTupleOps` instead of applying it yourself :

```
import shapeless.syntax.std.tuple._
class Tupling[L <: HList, TP <: Product](tupler: Tupler.Aux[L, TP]) {
  def toHList(value: TP)(implicit gen: Generic.Aux[TP, L]): L = 
    value.productElements
}
```

You could also add the implicit parameter to the constructor instead of the `toHList` function.